# Mercurial "No match found. Code 255" при апдейте

Tags: mercurial

Периодически Tortoise HG нормально скачивает новые изменения из репозитория, но при апдейте текущей ветки на них вываливает No match found со ссылкой на какой-нибудь файл. Пример на скрине (сюда постить картинки рейтинга не хватает)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LtdM.png
Как пролечить?

Comment: А если попробовать сделать checkout в отдельную папку, сработает? У меня есть подозрение, что какой-нибудь вредный антивирус просто заблокировал доступ к файлам. Я бы проверил, есть ли там файлы, на которые ругается Tortoise HG.

Comment: Делаю чекаут, спустя какое-то время фокус повторяется.
Репозиторий иногда переносится архивом между рабочим и домашним ПК, т.к. если каждый раз выкачивать - очень большой объём получается. Окружение аналогичное.
Defender отключен, использую DrWeb в минимальной конфигурации (сканер и защита) - он не матерится что что-то блокировал.
Файлы, на которые он матерится, как раз из репозитория и должны затянуться. Да и я вроде все локальные чейнджи отклоняю, т.е. хочу чтобы он полностью последнюю ветвь именно из репозитория восстановил

Comment: Носить репозиторий между компьютерами - не очень хорошая идея. Можно разрушить целостность или, что более вероятно, просто получить конфликт с правами. И, естественно, что если права нарушены (а при копировании это сделать легко, если файловая система NTFS), то доступ к файлу будет ограничен.